# Android SQLite Delete a row

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

My code:

```
public void droptablecontents(String category)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "DELETE FROM " + Table_Name + " WHERE " + KEY_CAT + "=" + category;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    cursor.close();
}
```

My table creation query:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + Table_Name + "(" + KEY_NOTE + " TEXT, " + KEY_CAT + " TEXT" + ")"
```

My log cat error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Ideas (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM Cats WHERE cat=Ideas
```

But why is it searching for a column named 'Ideas'? I am trying to search for the value 'Ideas' in the column KEY_CAT.

Comment: `String[] params = new String[]{ contact_no };
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("DELETE FROM  + Table_Name + " WHERE " + KEY_CAT + "= ?",
                   params);`

Comment: **"delete from "+Table_Name+" where "+KEY_CAT+" in ("
                + category + ")"**
Try this Query

Answer (score -1):

Add "'" for that were condition, it's text.

```
public void droptablecontents(String category)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "DELETE FROM " + Table_Name + " WHERE " + KEY_CAT + "='" + category + "'";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: This will blow up when the value contains a quote.